# "Find All" Feature In TextMate?

Tags: textmate, replace

Is there a way to "Find All" in TextMate?

Surely I'm missing something...

I see Find Previous, & Next, but no Find All.

This seems like such a standard thing, which is what makes me believe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Find All doesn't exist in the current version of TextMate, only Replace All.  You'll have to wait for [TextMate 2, which includes Find All as a feature](http://macromates.com/changes), or try another editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Find in Project", which gives you a list of matches grouped by files, as a workaround.